# Unterschied zwischen »ausharren«, »aushalten« und »abwarten«

Tags: difference, meaning

Worin unterscheiden sich die Wörter **ausharren**, **aushalten** und **abwarten**?

Im Duden werden unter [ausharren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausharren) die beiden anderen Wörter als Synonyme gelistet (u.a.).

*(Hinweis: ich habe das ursprüngliche Beispiel entfernt, weil es mir nicht um dieses konkret, sondern um die Wörter im Allgemeinen geht.)*

Comment: @user unknown: Das ist sehr Kontext-abhängig (er könnte zB großen Druck auf der Blase gehabt haben). Ich habe die Beispiele entfernt, es geht mir um die Wörter *im Allgemeinen*.

Comment: Kontextabhängig bitte klein und zusammen schreiben. Was konkret ist denn die Frage und wie weit haben Dich eigene Recherchen geführt? "Aushalten" hat kein Doppel-R, zum Beispiel.

Comment: @userunknown: [bitte dies beachten](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/850/16019)

Comment: @jor Das wurde, *de facto* [davon](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/915) überholt.

Comment: An den Close-Voter: zumindest "unclear what you're asking" halte ich angesichts einer akzeptierten Antwort für unangebracht.

Comment: I see how "ausharren" and "abwarten" can come across as the same thing in a dictionary but "aushalten" certainly not. As long as this is part of the question I'll vtc because of a lack of research/a lack of indication why research wasn't enough

Comment: @Emanuel When you open the [Duden page for _ausharren_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausharren) you'll find _aushalten_ listed among the synonyms. So IMHO it's quite natural to add it to the list.

Comment: @Matthias *Unclear* passt meines Erachtens sehr gut, denn hier stehen zwei Wörter (*ausharren* und *abwarten*) die meines Erachtens einen sehr unterschiedlichen Kontext haben.

Comment: @Jan Mein voriger Kommentar gilt 1:1 auch für _abwarten_. Abgesehen davon finde ich, dass die Existenz einer akzeptierten Antwort beweist, dass die Frage klar genug war, um eine den OP zufriedenstellende Antwort zu geben. Da muss man nicht noch nachträglich beckmessern. Für spätere Besucher sieht das sonst ziemlich verwirrend aus, IMHO eine Form von _broken window_.

Comment: @Matthias Ich sehe jetzt erst, dass seit zwei Stunden wenigstens ein *Link* auf den Duden gesetzt worden ist. Damit ist immerhin etwas klarer, was gefragt wird, und zumindest ich werde meine Schließstimme zurückziehen. Ob eine Frage geschlossen werden muss, darf (und soll) unabhängig von gegebenen und/oder akzeptierten Antworten sein; geschlossen heißt, dass die *Frage* schlecht war. Und nicht umsonst gibt es den *Reversal*-Badge.

Comment: @Jan: *Reversal* ist mittlerweile eher umstritten in seiner Sinnhaftigkeit. Und die Schließwürdigkeit einer Frage korreliert zwar mit ihrer Qualität, aber mehr auch nicht. Geschlossen sein heißt, dass die Frage nicht für diese Seite geeignet ist und nicht mehr beantwortet werden sollte, nicht dass sie schlecht ist. Es gibt schlechte Fragen, die offen bleiben sollten, und gute Fragen, die geschlossen werden müssen, wobei letztere sehr selten sind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ausharren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausharren) und die intransitive Form von [aushalten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aushalten#Bedeutung3) (nur diese, beachte den Link und siehe auch den Hinweis weiter unten!) sind Synonyme. Beide beschreiben das Verbleiben an einem Ort *trotz widriger Umstände*, die eigentlich das Verlassen des Ortes nahelegen würden. *Ausharren* betont dabei eher das Vergehen der Zeit, den Aspekt der Geduld, während *aushalten* eher das Ertragen der erwähnten Umstände und deren Bedrohlichkeit hervorhebt.

Mir fällt bei *aushalten* immer der Anfang der Ballade [*John Maynard*](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/gedichte-4455/23) von Theodor Fontane ein:

> John Maynard war unser Steuermann,
>   Aus hielt er, bis er das Ufer gewann, …

John Maynard war ein Kapitän, der sein brennendes Schiff nicht verließ, sondern es bis ans Ufer steuerte und so alle Passagiere rettete, dies aber selbst mit seinem Leben bezahlte. *Ausharren* würde hier nicht passen, denn er trotzte Rauch und Feuer, wohingegen der Zeitraum eher kurz gewesen sein dürfte.

*Aushalten* hat außerdem noch weitere Bedeutungen, von denen vor allem [*etwas aushalten*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aushalten#Bedeutung1), also eine Sache oder einen Umstand (z.B. Schmerz) ertragen, deutlich häufiger verwendet wird als das hier betrachtete *aushalten* im Sinne von *ausharren*.

[Abwarten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abwarten) ist hingegen ein eher neutraler Begriff, der das Warten auf das Eintreten einer Bedingung beschreibt oder auch das Aufschieben einer Entscheidung, bis sich neue Informationen ergeben.

Comment: ""ausharren" und "aushalten" sind Synonyme.". Nein, sind sie nicht. "aushalten" ist ein Synonym for "ausharren" aber anders rum ist es absolut nicht so. Mir ist klar, dass es dir um die beiden Verben in der einen Bedeutung geht, aber Lerndende wissen dies nicht und denken nach dem ersten Satz "Ah, ok, ich kann die einfach gegeneinander austauschen". Das sollte in der Antwort klar gemacht werden. -1 weil der erste Satz zu falscher Verwendung führt.

Comment: @Emanuel Ich finde zwar, dass auch Lernende wissen sollten, dass man einen Text bis zum Ende liest, aber sei's drum: ich hab den ersten Satz entsprechend disclaimert.

Answer (score 0):

So formuliert sollten die Unterschiede deutlich werden:

> Er harrte unter dem Vordach aus, bis der Regen vorüber war.
>
> Er hielt den Regen aus, ohne sich unter das Vordach zu stellen.
>
> Er wartete ab, bis der Regen nachließ, bevor er aus dem Haus ging.

Comment: Nein, sind sie nicht. "Er wartete unter dem Vordach ab, bis der...". Wo ist der Unterschied zu deinem ersten Beispiel?

Comment: @Emanuel Aushalten heisst auf jeden Fall, dass ich den Umständen direkt ausgesetzt bin. Ausharren kann ich auch in einem Versteck, würde ich jedoch dieses verlassen treffen die Umstände auch mich. Nimm statt Regen einen Sturm. Sturm aushalten. Ausharren - Irgendwo Schutz vor diesem suchen. Abwarten bis er vorüber ist, mich ihm also gar nicht erst aussetzen. Letzteres geht eben auch weit entfernt vom Sturm, wenn z.B. dahin reisen will wo er wütet.

Comment: Mach das doch in die Antwort.

Answer (score 0):

3 abwarten ist das normale Wort.

2 aushalten paßt nicht.

1 ausharren ist ein literarisches Wort, das in diesem Zusammenhang nur komisch wirkt.